# Apache 2.4.x manual build and install on RHEL 6.4

Tags: apache, apache2, redhat, rhel

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

The current yum installation of apache on this OS is 2.2.15. I require the latest 2.4.x branch so have gone about installing it manually. I have noted the complete procedure I undertook, including unpacking `apr` and `apr-util` sources into the apache sources beforehand, but I guess the following is the most important part of the procedure:

```
GATHER LATEST APACHE AND APR
$ cd ~
$ mkdir apache-src
$ cd apache-src
$ wget http://apache.insync.za.net//httpd/httpd-2.4.6.tar.gz
$ tar xvf httpd-2.4.6.tar.gz
$ cd httpd-2.4.6
$ cd srclib
$ wget http://apache.insync.za.net//apr/apr-1.5.0.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf apr-1.5.0.tar.gz
$ mv apr-1.5.0 apr
$ rm -f apr-1.5.0.tar.gz
$ wget http://apache.insync.za.net//apr/apr-util-1.5.3.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf apr-util-1.5.3.tar.gz 
$ mv apr-util-1.5.3 apr-util

INSTALL DEVEL PACKAGES
yum update --skip-broken (There is a dependency issue with the latest Chrome needing the latest libstdc++, which is not available for RHEL and CentOS)
yum install apr-devel
yum install apr-util-devel
yum install pcre-devel

INSTALL
$ cd ~/apache-src/httpd-2.4.6
$ ./configure --prefix=/etc/httpd --enable-mods-shared="all" --enable-rewrite --with-included-apr
$ make
$ make install
```

> NOTE: At the time of running the above, `/etc/http` is empty.

This seems to have gone fine until I attempt to start the httpd service. It seems that every module include in `httpd.conf` fails with a message similar to this one for `mod_rewrite`:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 148 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so: undefined symbol: ap_global_mutex_create
```

I've gone right through the list of enabled modules in `httpd.conf` and commented them out one at a time. All trigger an error as above, however the "undefined symbol: value" is often different (so not always `ap_global_mutex_create`).

Am I missing a step? Although I find a some portion of that error on Google, most of the solutions centre around the `.so` files not being reachable. That doesn't seem to be an issue here and the modules are present in `/etc/http/modules`.

> NOTE: At the time of running the above, `/etc/http` is empty.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have the correct procedure but it's incomplete.

After the installation you have to enable SSL in *httpd.conf*. and generate *server.crt* and *server.key* file.
Below the complete procedure :

**1. Download Apache**

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.4.23.tar.gz
tar xvf httpd-2.4.23.tar.gz
```

**2. Download APR and APR-Util**

```
cd /usr/src
wget -c http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/apache/apr/apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
wget -c http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/apache/apr/apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
tar xvf apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar xvf apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
```

Now put the APR and APR-Util you downloaded into your apache source files.

```
mv apr-1.5.2 /usr/src/httpd-2.4.23/srclib/apr
mv apr-util-1.5.4 /usr/src/httpd-2.4.23/srclib/apr-util
```

**3.Compile**

```
cd /usr/src/httpd-2.4.23
./configure --enable-so --enable-ssl --with-mpm=prefork --with-included-apr --with-included-apr-util
make
make install
```

As you can see in the `./configure` command we specify command line options to include apr and apr-utils.

**4. Enable SSL in httpd.conf**

Apache configuration file *httpd.conf* is located under */usr/local/apache2/conf*.

```
nano /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Uncomment the *httpd-ssl.conf* Include line and the `LoadModule ssl_module` line in the */usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf* file :

```
# LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
# Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

View the *httpd-ssl.conf* to review all the default SSL configurations. 
For most cases, you don’t need to modify anything in this file.

```
nano /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

The SSL certificate and key are required before we start the Apache. 
The *server.crt* and *server.key* file mentioned in the *httpd-ssl.conf* needs to be created before we move forward.

```
cd /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra
egrep 'server.crt|server.key' httpd-ssl.conf

SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key"
```

**5. Generate server.crt and server.key file**

First, Generate the *server.key* using openssl.

```
cd /usr/src
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
```

The above command will ask for the password. Make sure to remember this password. You need this while starting your Apache later.

Next, generate a certificate request file (*server.csr*) using the above *server.key* file.

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

Finally, generate a self signed ssl certificate (*server.crt*) using the above *server.key* and *server.csr* file.

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

Copy the *server.key* and *server.crt* file to appropriate Apache configuration directory location.

```
cp server.key /usr/local/apache2/conf/
cp server.crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/
```

**6. Start Apache**

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
```

If you are getting the below error message :

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 51 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLCipherSuite', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Make sure to uncomment the line shown below in *httpd.conf* :

```
vi /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

# LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

Finally, this will prompt you to enter the password for your private key before starting up the apache.
Verify that the Apache httpd process is running in the background.

```
ps -ef | grep http
```

You should see something like that :

```
root    29529 1     0 13:08 ? 00:00:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
antoine 29530 29529 0 13:08 ? 00:00:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
antoine 29531 29529 0 13:08 ? 00:00:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
antoine 29532 29529 0 13:08 ? 00:00:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
root    29616 18260 0 13:09 pts/0 00:00:00 grep http
```

By default Apache SSL runs on 443 port. Open a web browser and verify that you can access your Apache using *https://{your-ip-address}*

I hope this help, else I advise you to go see : http://jasonpowell42.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/install-apache-2-4-4-on-centos-6-4/

Comment: how to make it auto start with server?

Comment: @AntoineSubit Great post. I followed it for RedHat and it works well. Just a minor correction in Step 3. Compile `./configure --enable-so --enable-ssl --with-mpm=prefork --with-included-apr --with-included-apr-util`

Comment: @Capricorn Thanks. I edit my answer with your correction

Answer (score 7):

```
baprutil-1.la /usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr/libapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetEntityDeclHandler'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetUserData'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_StopParser'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [htpasswd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/support'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/httpd-2.4.27/support'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

This error is received in `make` step if `--with-included-apr-util` is not specified in `./configure`

Comment: Have you got the solution for your problem