# Undefined reference to XML_GetErrorCode (and others) when building Apache

Tags: java, linux, apache, httpd.conf

I am trying to build Apache httpd-2.4.33 on RHEL 7 version. I have configured the packages apr-1.6.3,apr-util-1.6.1, pcre-8.42.

While building at final stage i got this error:

```
.33/modules/aaa -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/cache -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/core -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/database -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/filters -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/ldap -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/loggers -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/lua -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/proxy -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/session -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/ssl -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/test -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/server -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/md -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/arch/unix -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/dav/main -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/generators -I/opt/httpd-2.4.33/modules/mappers  -prefer-non-pic -static -c passwd_common.c && touch passwd_common.lo
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -pthread         -o htpasswd  htpasswd.lo passwd_common.lo       /opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.la /opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetEntityDeclHandler'
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate'
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetUserData'
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_StopParser'
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/opt/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr_util/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [htpasswd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/httpd-2.4.33/support'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/httpd-2.4.33/support'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: I think the error message quote is incomplete: `.33/modules/aaa`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache 2.4.x manual build and install on RHEL 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45831604/608639). See Capricorn's answer. Also see [Problems building httpd-2.4.26 with apr-1.6.2 and apr-util-1.6.0](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/apr-dev/201706.mbox/%3CCAJtcoLauYUCHERDucRLG-EAm839cTD6D2x0QWUuEvHYEHS-mDg@mail.gmail.com%3E) on the Apache=dev mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
yum install expat-devel
```

before installing *Apache*. I got this error when installing `mod-wsgi-standalone` on *Amazon Linux*, but maybe this solution also helps in the general case.